# 6+8=71 move two matches

Tags: matches

How can I make this equation true by moving two matches?

[image]

It's in a game "Smart Puzzles" - it's called Matches, and there are about 13 different games in it.

---

**Additional images** - my attempts

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Move two matches to do what? To make the equation true?

Comment: Just to be clear - can matches be rotated or can they only be lifted and placed?

Comment: Yes the rotate when you put them where you want them

Comment: I can't make it a times but I can make it a subtraction

Comment: Yes to make the question true.

Comment: I posted an additional post with more pictures I couldn't figure out how to add pictures.

Comment: I assume 6+8<71 isn't a valid move?

Comment: Just a quick note that you should generally only post a puzzle that is of your creation.

Comment: @MobileGlick **With the creator’s permission and giving them proper attribution**, noteworthy puzzles not created by the poster are entirely welcome, as are puzzles the poster is asking a question about (including “How do I solve this?”).  If you post a puzzle as a challenge, we do prefer it be your own, but there’s no such rule saying it must (or even should) be your own.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Sorry for the oversimplification.

Answer (score 23):

> Change the six to a nine, and the seven and one change places by moving the top match along : $9+8=17$.

Or:

> Make the eight into a nine, and put the match into the six to make an eight. Same trick with $17$ to get $8+9=17$.

Comment: Alternatively, move the top two sticks of the seven and flip upside down

Answer (score 5):

Well you could easily

> Remove the horizontal match from the $+$ then place it between $7$ and $1$. Now replace the horizontal match with the one in the middle of the $8$ to get $6+0=7-1$.
>
>  EDIT: If removing the bottom match in the $+$ isn't considered "one move" then you can just as easily move the top one and rotate the two moved matches to satisfy $6+0=7-1$

If there is some leniency for spacing you could also

> Move the vertical $+$ match and horizontal $7$ match to make $6-8=-1-1$

Comment: Massive nit pick, but the horizontal match in the plus is underneath, so technically this would involve moving three matches!

Comment: @JMP clarification from OP - "Yes the rotate when you put them where you want them" so I could remove the top one instead and still replace it from the $8$

Answer (score 2):

Cheating, I know, but:

> $$6 - 8 \ne 17$$

or

> $$6 - 8 \ne 71$$

if you're lazy and only want to move one match.

Comment: I think there's generally an unspoken rule in these kind of puzzles that you can't mess with the equals sign...

Comment: Hence "Cheating" @DarrelHoffman. *8')

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this counts :)

> Move one match diagonally across the equals to make it not equals, then move any other match so that the equation is still not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

> Move the top horizontal match of the 6 and the top horizontal match of the 7 to the 1 to make the latter into a 4.

Answer (score 0):

> $6 + 2 = 7 + 1$ (two matches from $8$ to make a plus between $7$ and $1$)

Answer (score 0):

The 6 become 9 (move bottom left to top right) and then remove the top match from the seven and put it on top of the 1. So the equation become 9+8 = 17